# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php on line 80

Tags: magento

I installed a theme for the admin. Refreshed cache and it looked great. I went to log out and log back in and received following error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php on line 80
```

Lines 65-89:

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return 86400;
}

/**
 * Get Key pieces for caching block content
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $cacheKeyInfo = array(
        'admin_top_nav',
        $this->getActive(),
        Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId(),
        Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()
    );
    // Add additional key parameters if needed /
    $additionalCacheKeyInfo = $this->getAdditionalCacheKeyInfo();
    if (is_array($additionalCacheKeyInfo) && !empty($additionalCacheKeyInfo)) {
        $cacheKeyInfo = array_merge($cacheKeyInfo, $additionalCacheKeyInfo);
    }
    return $cacheKeyInfo;
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUserId()` instead.